# How to force telegram to update the link preview?

Tags: seo, telegram

Telegram show description meta tag as link preview.
I changed the description meta tag but the link preview of my website didn't changed.
How to force telegram to update link preview?

Answer (score 258, accepted):

Go to [@webpagebot](https://telegram.me/webpagebot) and send the link (up to 10) you want to update. Automatically will scan your site and generate the new image thumbnail, site name and description.

Remember to have og prefix in your `html` tag as: `<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">` or telegram bot will not update the graph cache.

[via telegramgeeks](http://telegramgeeks.com/2016/03/you-can-update-link-preview-telegram/)

Comment: How I can tell telegram to run my javascript code before capturing meta data?

Comment: I think it's not supported.

Comment: @rezcash ask Telegram support for this.

Comment: I’ve tried it, it doesn’t work when I update my website.

Comment: @Gabriel try again or ask Telegram support.

Comment: I forgot to add `prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"` to the `head`.  After added this Telegram bot updated preview of my website.

Comment: @rezCash You can't. Meta data is in the <meta> tag. javascript is not ran by a server, only a browser can interpret it.

Comment: @rezKesh use server side rendering

Comment: @AvenDesta yes, it's official bot.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the og prefix in the `html` tag isn't required anymore.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. Though I would have never guessed I'm supposed to do this manually just for my website description to show correctly on Telegram link previews...

Comment: Worked awesome.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work anymore! [Jan 2024]

Answer (score 20):

You may add `/?v=n` at the end of URL when sharing the link, where `n` can be any number and should increase after an update.

Comment: works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Sending the pure link to @webpagebot would not work so I used

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://mylink.com" />
```

and it worked.

Comment: The mentioned bot is not to generate preview for you (w/o appropriate meta-tag)!

Answer (score 1):

Actually it still works, added this line of code to my html head:

```
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" />
```

then move to telegram bot and update your link 10 times:https://telegram.me/webpagebot?.

Once you have done that, you can copy your link again and the preview comes out.