# Telegram not updating link preview from github

Tags: telegram

I changed my profile picture on github quite some time ago, but whenever I share a link to any of my repositories via telegram, it still displays old profile pic. If I share it via skype, correct image is displayed.

I tried to use webpage bot and `/updatepreview` command, it says that "Link previews was updated successfully. Check them out!" but the image is still the same (not updated)!

How can I make telegram clean cache for links from my github account?

Answer (score 5):

I used [webpagebot](https://telegram.me/webpagebot) like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35793374/3262021) from another thread to fix my GitHub avatar and it is working for me.

After giving the URL to the bot, I had to push Update with Content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried appending `/?v=n` at the end of the URL when sharing the link? `n` can be any number but should be increasing after every update you make

Comment: I think the point is to have this work on arbitrary github repo links, begging the question what image link is used for that.