# From where Telegram is taking the thumbnail of my website link?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

In my website I have set the `<meta property="og:image">` tag to the image I want to be used as thumbnail; it's working correctly on Facebook, Twitter and all other social networks when I share a link from my site:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.myurl.com/images/postshare.jpg" />
```

But somehow Telegram is showing another image and this image is not even on any tags of my site.

I already tried to use the bot to update the image, but it still shows this image. I don't know where it is coming from.

What can I do? Besides `og:image`, is there any other tag I should use?

Comment: [This StackOverflow answer might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35793374/5625547)

Comment: It might a problem on their side (a bug or caching), you can try to setup a different site, maybe just a different page. I didnt have any problem with my image being provided as og:image